# Routing Module loads before APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a value that is from of a config file from static AppConfigService.
 Described below:

reference code/article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/03/01/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfig } from './app-config';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {

static settings: AppConfig;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
load() {
    console.log('is this getting fired before routing module check?');
    const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`;
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(jsonFile)
            .toPromise()
            .then((response: AppConfig) => {
                AppConfigService.settings = <AppConfig>response;
                console.log(AppConfigService.settings);
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((response: any) => {
                reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': 
${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            });
    });
}

}
```

This config gets loaded in my `APP_INITIALIZER` in the `app.module.ts`

```
  providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (appConfigService: AppConfigService) => () => {appConfigService.load() },
      deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true
    }
  ],
```

but my routing module, named `AppRoutingModule` is reading something out of my `AppConfigService.settings` variable which is crazy enough, UNDEFINED. My application crashes. I expect the `APP_INITIALIZER` to fire BEFORE `AppRoutingModule` but this is not the case:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'oldUrl' of undefined`

`oldUrl` is a property of `AppConfigService.settings`. I checked if `AppConfigService.settings` is set, it IS, properly AFTER routing module is fired but this is not what I want.

I checked some other sources for help. I used the following already as maybe a fix: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14615 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14588

```
@component({})
class App {
constructor(router: Router, loginService: LoginService) {
loginService.initialize();
router.initialNavigation();
}
}

@NgModule({
imports: [
BrowserModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {initialNavigation: false})
],
declarations: [ App ],
bootstrap: [ App ],
providers: [ Guard, LoginService ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Unfortunately, the above solution is not fixing my problem. I also tried to put in `AppModule` but alas, that didn't help either.

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: why is your routing module dependent on a config?

Comment: For some routing to an old application, as this issue is old I moved on to another solution for my problem. I removed any depedencies on the config from the routing module.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my App Initialization and Routing with NgRx listening the central state to know when the system is Loaded and activating the route Guards after that.

But for a direct solution, you need to add a Route Guard checking when your service is loaded. So, add a `loaded: boolean` flag in your Service, and check it from a Guard like this:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14615#issuecomment-352993695

This is better handled with Observables tho, and I'm wiring all with NgRx in my Apps using Facades to facilitate everything:
https://gist.github.com/ThomasBurleson/38d067abad03b56f1c9caf28ff0f4ebd

Best regards.